# Android Eclipse Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing an android application with eclipse and cannot seem to solve these errors which are cropping up. I am new to developing and your help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

My errors are here http://oi50.tinypic.com/2hflzc8.jpg

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.easyfindme;


import com.example.easyfindme.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class EasyFindMe extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_easy_find_me);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(android.R.menu.activity_easy_find_me, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: android.R refer to system resource in the OS. If you want to reference your own resource use <your package>.R (com.example.easyfindme.R).

Answer (score 2):

use

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy_find_me);
```

instead of

```
setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_easy_find_me);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include your R.java file, not android.R ..

```
setContentView(android.R.layout.activity_easy_find_me); //is wrong
setContentView(com.example.easyfindme.R.layout.activity_easy_find_me); //is right
```

Answer (score 0):

//dont use

```
android.R.layout.activity_easy_find_me
```

use as

```
R.layout.activity_easy_find_me
```

// for menu you need seperate xml in menu folder. layout xml wont work.

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menuxml, menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to the following code

```
 public class EasyFindMe extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_easy_find_me);<========== here
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_easy_find_me, menu);<======== here
return true;
}
}
```

It's a problem with using android.R.xxxx in your layout. that's the problem.